# ASP.NET - View model with only partial domain model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, model, viewmodel

What is the best course of action when I want to use a view model and I want to include data about an entity that exists in my domain model, but I do not want to include everything that's in the domain model. I have thought of 3 possibilities, which one would be the most appropriate one? I'm using MVC 4 with VS 2013.

1. Just implementing the specific attributes I want to use in my view model and map them? (I feel like that's bad because when having an array of the reduced domain model, it would make looping through the array way harder because the attributes are unrelated)
2. Add another view model that maps to the domain model and only these specific attributes? (This feels bad as well since it would detach view models from views because there suddenly are view models without a corresponding view)
3. Add another model with only the specific attributes and include that in my view model? (My models are autogenerated with EF 5.0, so I would rather not mess with the structure of the models)
4. Just include the whole domain model and take the overhead?
5. Any other possibility I haven't thought of?

Comment: The entire point of using a viewmodel is to have an object that holds the fields that usually correspond to the fields in one of your domain objects. Often you can just copy-paste the properties of your domain model into your viewmodel so I'm not sure where exactly your confusion lays. Take the properties you need and put them in the viewmodel.

Comment: I did describe copy-pasting the properties to my domain model in alternative 1, my concern with this is that my view model has to include an array of that certain domain model (or rather its parts) and it would make it harder to loop through my results since the attributes are not connected. Also I'm scared that they may be in a different order or generally not relatable to each other.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to go for an inner class in my view model, representing only those properties of the domain model that I actually want to use. Then I could map the domain model to the inner class model and it worked quite well.

I'm still not sure what's "best practise" in this case, if such a thing exists for a task as simple as that.